# String Delimiting in sql server taking Input from a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, delimiter

I'm using Delimiting Strings, in sql server

I have a function like

```
select * from fnSplit('1,22,333,444,,5555,666')
```

Which splits the string into a table. But now I need to take the input from a table.
I have 10 Rows which contain the Limited Strings separated by comma like `1,22,333`.
I need to take every row and use the function `fnSplit` on it and return all the values in a single table. How can I do this ???

Comment: - show us the code for your function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.mytable t
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.fnSplit(t.mycolumn) y
) y
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
Select 
   distinct y.*
from
   mytable x 
   full outer join dbo.fnSplit(x.mycolumn) y ON 1=1
```

But I think this is very inefficient - show us the code for your function.